# Windows Phone access to Artists/Album in collection

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, xbox-music

I am writing an xbox music based app and find myself needing to get a list of the current music in a users collection.
I have seen how to access all of the Artists using KnownFolder.MusicLibrary but this seems to only access music that is stored on the phone.
I want to access the 'Collection' of music on the phone, including music that is streaming only, i.e. not currently stored on the phone so has no physical folder.
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah never mind, I was too focused on browsing the phone itself.
It's actually accessed through the music API:
/1/content/{namespace}/collection/{type}/browse

Would have been nice to be able to do this without needing to be online but can work with it at least :)

Comment: Hmm to make this a little more interesting, I just tried debugging on my actual phone and the KnownFolders method did actually list all artists. including ones that are not currently downloaded so we may be able to do this offline after all. But now I have a question about the emulator. I loaded a few albums on the fake SD card and ran KnownFolders for MusicLibrary but it found nothing, as far as I was aware the Deep Links care not where the music is actually stored. So how to debug without using a real phone..?